# Parse Json if a certain value exists

Tags: python, json

I need to parse "order" from below JSON , if only value of "success" = 'true' , else raise an exception.

Tried below, but not sure how to include the 'true' check in try:

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "order":"123345"
}
```

below is the code , I am trying , which is not giving any result from print as well.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


data = json.load(open('data.json'))
#pprint(data)

try:
    check_key = data['success']
except KeyError:
    #continue
    print(check_key)
   #print(data['order'])
```

Comment: You are trying to print `check_key` only in the case that it does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should evaluate data['success'] in a condition, whether it is false, then you raise your exception.

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json'))

if data['success'] is not True:
  raise Exception("Success is false")

order = data['order']
print(order)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to test `== False`, unless you really need to make sure that other falsey values (like `None`) are not treated as false, while at the same time making sure that really weird objects that are not `False` but define a `__eq__` that claims to be equal to it _are_ treated as false.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to parse "order" from below JSON , if only value of "success" = 'true' , else raise an exception.

There's no function that will automatically raise an exception if a value is False; you need to write that yourself.

But it's dead easy:

```
check_key = data.get('success')
if not check_key:
    raise MyKindOfError(f'response success was {check_key}')
do_stuff(data['order'])
```

(You don't actually need to use `get` there; you *could* let `data['success']` raise a `KeyError` if it's not present, and then separately check the value for falsiness and raise your own error. But I assume you probably want to handle a missing `success` the same way as `false`, and the error you want to raise probably isn't `KeyError`, in which case this is simpler.)

---

As a side note, *you've already parsed the JSON at this point*. What you have is a `dict`.

The fact that it originally came from parsing JSON doesn't make any difference; it's a plain old Python `dict`, with all the same methods, etc., as any other `dict`. So, it really isn't helpful to think of "how do I … with JSON …"; that just misleads you into forgetting about how easy `dict`s are to use.